# How to set WorkManager to upload in background

Tags: android, kotlin, intentservice, android-workmanager

How i can use workmanager to do background upload work, i have app that backup my files to the pc via FTP, and i wana learn the new way, because on my phone the old way its only work when i have app up and running when i close app the background task stop.
Can soneone help me set up the workmanager

```
class Working(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
private val TAG = ""
private val SERVER = ""
private val USERNAME = ""
private val PASSWORD = ""
private val PATH = ""
private val timer = Timer()
override fun doWork(): ListenableWorker.Result {
    Log.i(TAG, "UploadJobService onStartJob")
    UploadFile(applicationContext).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, PATH, SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    var uploadTask = UploadFile(applicationContext)
    timer.schedule(UploadTick(uploadTask, applicationContext),0, 1 * 10000)
    return UploadTick.Result.SUCCESS
}
internal class UploadTick(task: UploadFile, ctx: Context): TimerTask() {
    private val SERVER = ""
    private val USERNAME = ""
    private val PASSWORD = ""
    private val PATH = ""

    private var _task = task
    private val _context = ctx

    override fun run() {
        Log.d("UploadTick", _task.status.toString())
        if(_task.status == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
            _task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, PATH, SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        } else if(_task.status == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            _task = UploadFile(_context)
            _task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, PATH, SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        }
    }
}

companion object {

    private val TAG = UploadTick::class.java.simpleName
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Two solutions:

1. Use alarm manager with IntentService to schedule the task periodically even app is in the background like this:

   ```
   final AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   final Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);

   if (pendingIntent == null) {
       pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
   }
       manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), INTERVAL_TIME_MILLIS, pendingIntent);
   }
   ```
2. Use work manager and schedule it periodically like this:

   ```
   WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(new 
   PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(FiveDayDataApiDownloader.class, 24, 
   TimeUnit.HOURS).setConstraints(new 
   Constraints.Builder().setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true).build()).build());
   ```